# Monotone convergence for McShane (Lebesgue) integral (step in a proof)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The theorem states

> Let $f$ be a function on a cell $A$ and let $f_n$ be a sequence of McShane (Lebesgue) integrable functions such that, $f_n\le f$ and $f_n\to f$. Than, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_A f_n d\alpha$ is finite, than $$\int_A fd\alpha =\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_A f_nd\alpha$$

Now, let
$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A f_nd\alpha$$
and $$A=\cup_{i=0}^kA_i$$

The proof states

> The theorem is proved by showing that $$|\sum_{i=0}^k f(x_i)\alpha(A_i) - I|<\epsilon|2-\alpha(A)|\tag{1}\label{1}$$

#### Question

As $\alpha(A_i)=\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$ where $b$ and $a$ are the endpoints of the interval $A_i$, how can this be so? Suppose the range of $\alpha$ is $\mathbb{R}$. Does that not make the right hand side of \eqref{1} infinite? Surely the $\alpha(A)$ must be finite?

Please help me understand, I do not know why $\eqref{1}$ implies the theorem. As a self taught amateur, I have no one but stackexchange to ask...

#### Edit

To clarify, I know how to prove the theorem, if $I$ assume that the stateent \eqref{1} implies the theorem, as I know how to prove \eqref{1}. My problem is, that I do not understand why \eqref{1} implies the theorem, if, lets say, $\alpha(A)=\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$ is not finite, because lets say, $a$ or $b$ are not finite. Than It would seem that the right hand side of \eqref{1} is not finite. So how does \eqref{1} imply the theorem **even when $\alpha(A)$ is not finite?**

Comment: Probably, you may want to recall how to define $\int f d\alpha$. Starting from simple functions, bounded functions, and non-negative functions...

Comment: @induction601 Thank you for your comment. Yes, I recall the definition, I am looking at it in the book as I write this. There is no mentioning of it having to be finite ($\alpha(A)$). Looking at my question, is it your opinion that $\alpha(A)$ has to be finite, for the (1) to imply the theorem?

Comment: @induction601 I added an edit to clarify my question. If you know, please provide an answer, I would be most grateful.

Comment: It is not necessarily to $\alpha(A)$ be finite. For example, let $A = [1,\infty)$. Then $\alpha(A) = \infty$, however, $\int f d\alpha < \infty$ when $f(x) = 1/n^2$ where $x \in [n,n+1)$.

Comment: In theorem, it is only required $\lim_n \int f_n d\alpha < \infty$ not $\alpha(A) < \infty$. $\alpha(A)$ could be infinte. For example let $f_n(x) = 1/k^2$ when $x \in [k,k+1)$ for $1\le k <n$ and $f_n(x) = 0$ when $x \in [n, \infty)$. Note that $\lim_n f_n = f$ as I defined above. Then as theorem stated, $\lim_n \int f_n d\alpha = \int f d\alpha < \infty$.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. I think that when $\alpha(A) < \infty$, (1) implies theorem. However, you can always divide integral into countable integal with finite $A_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \cup_{i=1}^n A_i$ with $\alpha(A_i) < \infty$ and $A_i$'s are disjoint. 
WLOG, say $\alpha(A_i) = 1$. 
Then suppose 
$\int_A f_n d\alpha < \infty$. Then one can write
$$ \int_A f_n d\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{A_i} f_nd\alpha.$$
Thus let $I = \sum_{i=1}^\infty I_i = \int_A f d\alpha$ where $I_i = \int_{A_i} fd\alpha$.
Thus it suffices to show that for each $i$, 
$$ \left|I_i - \int_{A_i} f_n d\alpha \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2^i}.$$ 
Because this implies
$$ \left|I - \int_A f_n d\alpha \right| \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty\left|I_i - \int_{A_i} f_n d\alpha \right| < \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{2^i} \le \epsilon. $$

Comment: First, many thanks for your time! Please tell me if I understood correctly. In my question, (1) implies the theorem only when $A_i$ is finite. BUT, as you had shown, we can use such a theorem on an infinite collection of $A_i$, (where $A=\cup_{i=0}^\infty A_i$) and show that (as the theorem holds on any finite $A_i$) the sum over the $A_is$ must converge as well. Sorry for the follow up, I am pretty tired, and want to be sure I understood you, before I go to bed :)

Comment: Yes, you got my point!

Comment: Thank you! I am a self taught amateur, I really appreciate such help! Thanks again!